# FastReport error CS0103: The name ' ' does not exist in the current context

Tags: wpf, fastreport

You can see I put JobData under Job, Job under Project. This is how I construct data:

[image]

Here is the code in `frx` file:

```
<Dictionary>
  <BusinessObjectDataSource Name="Project" ReferenceName="ProjectRef" DataType="System.Int32" Enabled="true">
    <Column Name="Id" DataType="System.String"/>
    <Column Name="Name" DataType="System.String"/>
    <Column Name="Description" DataType="System.String"/>
    <BusinessObjectDataSource Name="Job" ReferenceName="JobRef" DataType="System.Int32" Enabled="true">
      <Column Name="Id" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="ProjectId" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="Name" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="Description" DataType="System.String"/>
      <BusinessObjectDataSource Name="JobData" ReferenceName="JobDataRef" DataType="System.Int32" Enabled="true">
        <Column Name="Id" DataType="System.String"/>
        <Column Name="JobId" DataType="System.String"/>
        <Column Name="Name" DataType="System.String"/>
        <Column Name="Value" DataType="System.String"/>
        <Column Name="Description" DataType="System.String"/>
      </BusinessObjectDataSource>
    </BusinessObjectDataSource>
  </BusinessObjectDataSource>
</Dictionary>
```

I just want to know if fastreport supports this structure? If Yes, Please tell me how to use.
Because in this way, people who create the report will easily see what is the relation between each datatable.